# Branded / Opaque type for aliasing any in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am use to build TS code using branded types with this little snippet

```
type Brand<Base, Brand> = Base & { __brand: Brand }
```

and this way emulate nominal typing

```
type Euro = Brand<number, "Euro">
type Dollar = Brand<number, "Dollar">
let e: Euro ;
let d: Dollar;

d = e // Type Euro is not assignable to type Dollar
```

I'd like to know if I could do the same with the `any` type and brand it in order to distinguish in my codebase the different usecases of this infamous any such as

```
type NeedCodec = Brand<any, "NeedCodec">
type TodoLater = Brand<any, "TodoLater">

let x: NeedCodec;
let y: TodoLater;

x = y // sadly works
```

I understand that `any` is kind of the joker type and once its encounter loose the type system, but I would like to know if there is a way to distinguish 2 any types.

I want that because I dont want the name to be resolved in `any` but keep the original name `NeedCodec`.

[image: imgur.com/a/LhxMaJg]

I want in the hover to have x: NeedCodec

Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: I sincerely doubt this is possible, but I don't understand the use case so I don't know how to recommend alternatives.  What would you want to do with values of the `NeedCodec` and `TodoLater` types? I know you *don't* want them to be mutually assignable, but I don't know what you *do* want to do with them.  Could you show some examples?

Comment: Would unknown instead of any work?

Comment: Unknown would work but i would be force to cast it back as any with `as` everytime i would use it . `cont x: NeedCodec = 'whatever' as any`